# Application exits without notice/error when triggering a breakpoint

Tags: crash, xamarin.ios, debugging, breakpoints

I just upgraded to the latest version of both MonoDevelop and MonoTouch and now whenever I try to hit a break point the simulator just exits.  Nothing to the application output either.  Anyone else seeing this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a breakpoing in your startup path.  iOS has a watchdog, and if you do not return from FinishedLaunching within 10 seconds it will kill your applicaiton.

Answer (score 1):

I am seeing the same issue, using MonoTouch 5.3.6 (Alpha release) along with monodevelop 3.0.4.5. I am going to try and revert to a older version. My problem occurs if I have a breakpoint anywhere in the application.

#### Update

I tracked down the issue to TestFlight. I would experience very odd behavior debugging in the simulator, for instance any breakpoint in the application would cause the application to exit. Also timers and other things didn't work right. However doing a release in the simulator worked fine. I hope this information helps someone.

Comment: I tried downgrading to the stable releases of Monotouch and Monodevelop and the issue persists.

Comment: I tracked down the issue to TestFlight. I would experience very odd behavior debugging in the simulator, for instance any breakpoint in the application would cause the application to exit. Also timers and other things didn't work right. However doing a release in the simulator worked fine. I hope this information helps someone.

Comment: TestFlight was the culprit for me as well. Updated your answer to make that a bit more obvious for others that come here with the same issue.